# Autowired bean is null

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have read a lot of questions about autowiring on Stackoverflow but I still cannot figure why my autowiring does not work.

I have a standard directory structure :

```
com.mycompany
  |-controller
  |-service
  |-model
```

When I inject Services from Controllers, everything works fine. But when I try to give a custom implementation of `UserDetailService` to spring security, it fails:

```
@Service
public class MyCustomUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {

  @Autowired
  private UserService userService; //This attribute remains null

  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    try {
      User userByEmail = userService.findUserByEmail(email); //NullPointerException
      return new UserDetailsAdapter(userByEmail);
    } catch(NoResultException e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

`UserService` is a very simple Service, anotated with `@Service` :

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class UserService {
  [...]
}
```

Note : UserService is correctly autowired when instantiated from UserController :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

  @Autowired
  private UserService service; //This one works!
```

Here is the dispatcher-servlet.xml (see the component-scan) :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany"/>
  <tx:annotation-driven/>
  <mvc:annotation-driven/>
</beans>
```

And here is the relevant part of the Spring context :

```
<beans:bean id="customUserDetailService" class="com.mycompany.service.customUserDetailService"/>

<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailService">
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that your problem is related to the fact that the your bean is managed by the `DispatcherServlet` context instead of the root context. By putting the `<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany"/>` in the `DispatcherServlet` context, all the beans scanned on these packages would be managed by the `DispatcherServlet` context and are not visible by the root context which is the one that manage your `MyCustomUserDetailService` bean.

The `DispatcherServlet` is a child of the root context and that allows your core beans from the root context to be injected into the view-layer beans like controllers. The visibility is only one way, you can't inject beans from the `DispatcherServlet` context into a bean manage by the root context, that's why it works in the `UserController` but not in the `MyCustomUserDetailService`.

Moving the `<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany"/>` tag to the root context (Spring context) should do the trick.